# In Gauss' Law, how is the choice of $\epsilon_0$ practical for graphically illustrating field lines?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, vector-fields

In Gauss' Law the constant $ \epsilon_0 $  was chosen as the proportionality factor between line density and field intensity. In a theoretical sense, this is considered a wise choice because it leads to the conclusion that the total number of field lines is equal to the enclosed charge.

Why is such a choice considered practical for graphically illustrating field lines?

Comment: "Number of field lines" makes no sense. You can draw infinite field lines.

Answer (score 0):

In Gauss' Law, $\epsilon_0$ is a necessary proportionality constant to make the units consistent, as well as to model the permittivity of the vacuum. (In addition, this constant appears first in the textbook treatment of Coulomb's Law where it precedes Gauss' Law.)

(The phrase "total number of field lines is equal to the enclosed charge"
doesn't make sense from the point of view of units.)